# xargs and argument position

Tags: xargs, unix

I have a directory with a couple of PHP files in multiple levels. I want to execute the following command for all of these PHP files.

```
php ../../i18n/add-textdomain.php -i bulk-delete file_name.php
```

So, I wrote the following `find` command and piped it to `xargs`

```
find . -iname "*.php" -type f -print0| xargs -0 php ../../i18n/add-textdomain.php -i bulk-delete
```

The `php` command expects the PHP file to be the last argument. I assumed `xargs` will append the files listed by `find` at the end. But this doesn't seem to be happening.

How to tell `xargs` to add the arguments at the end of the command?

Comment: `xargs` does append the items in `stdin` to the end of the command by default.  You can use `-I` to override that, but it seems that something else is going wrong for you.  Do you need only one PHP file per command? If so, use `-n 1`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It seems the problem is not with the position, but that I needed one file per command. I added `-n1` as you suggested and it works now. Can you post it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xargs` does append the items in `stdin` to the end of the command by default.  You can use `-I` to override that, but it seems that something else is going wrong for you.  Do you need only one PHP file per command? If so, use `-n 1`.